# Ol3+boostrap-grid on big screen-resolution: container-fluid & height:100% => initial vertical scrollbar on Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, openlayers-3

I'm struggling with responsive layout with Bootstrap and OL3.

Using the Simple Example from http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/simple.html

When I open this example as "Stand-alone" (no openlayers.org-layout etc.) on **Firefox** (38.05 with resolution 1366x76) there will always be a map which is too big (vertical scrollbar) - it exceeds the window height at certain window-width (1200px).

see screenshot:
imgur.com/OJV5zxQ

It works properly when i use the "container" instead of the "container-fluid" class. But i want a responsive layout where the map uses the maximium space available.
I couldn't found anything looking through the boostrap.css (max-width/min-width: 1200px) concerning the problem.

I guess it has something to do with the ol.js generating the canvas width/height. But i'm not sure.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <div id="map">
    </div>
     <div id="info">
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b335z4n6/ 
On jsfiddle it might not work (its map.updateSize() related there, I think), so just copy the code of the simple-example into a html-file and open it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple example</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.6.0/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.6.0/ol.js"></script>
<style>
* { margin:0; padding:0; } /* to remove the top and left whitespace */
html { height: 100%; }

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.container-fluid {
    max-width: 99%;
    max-height: 99%; //this removes the "initial" scrollbar on Chromium but not on FF
    }
</style>
<style>
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container-fluid {
        border:1px solid red;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
<script>
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem above appears only when the OL-Container (here #map) doesn't have a fixed height given, like:

```
<div id="map" style="height:500px;"></div>
```

For the moment i will use the [jquery $(window).height()](https://api.jquery.com/height/) function and put the value into the #map-container.

THis seems to "fix" it - not the best solution so far...